# Enabling 2 different models in a rails app talk to the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I'm having a few integration issues. I have 2 models which need to be mapped so as to enable them to talk to the same table. So one model has a few attributes that are mapped to the corresponding columns in the table and likewise for the other model.

I've heard of aliasing, a technique that can be used. Help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create your two model and define the same table_name

```
  class ProjectComplete < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "projects"
  end

  class ProjectLittle < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "projects"
  end
```

Comment: FYI, set_table_name is now a deprecated method, resulting in the following warning: "Calling set_table_name is deprecated. Please use `self.table_name = 'the_name'` instead."