# Two different classes for the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem with a relationship that I dont how exactly to code. I been looking at the rails guide but no luck.

I have 3 Models: User, Owner and Company.

- User belongs_to Company / Company has_many Users
- Company belongs_to Owner / Owner has_one Company

The problem is the next: User and Owner are the same models, I now it is possible that two different classes use the same Model. But I don't know how to do that. Could someone give me a hand with these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: for same model do you mean same database table? If so take a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456061/enabling-2-different-models-in-a-rails-app-talk-to-the-same-table

Comment: why u would like to have two models? why you are not considering the user model as owner?

Comment: Emyl, yes that's one approach. Didn't know you could do that. I'll take note about this one too. Very useful info. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define associations like this:

```
Company has_many users, dependent: :destroy
User belongs_to company
User has_one company
```

If your company table has column call owner_id, define this:

```
Company belongs_to owner, class_name: "User"
```

If your company table has column call user_id, define this:

```
Company belongs_to owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: user_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kien Thanh.